# Match and group each term and operator of expression using regex

Tags: java, regex

I've searched several posts trying figure out a way to retrieve each term and operator of expressions like the following:

```
`now`+`1 day`-`2 days`
```

For this expression, I'd like to have 5 groups: now, +, 1 day, -, 2 days.

The regex I've come up with is the following:

```
`(never|now|\d+\s+(?:millisecond|second|minute|hour|day|year)s?)`(?:\s*(\+|\-)\s*`(never|now|\d+\s+(?:millisecond|second|minute|hour|day|year)s?)`)*
```

However, with this regex, I only get three groups: now, -, 2 days. What changes should I make in order to get every single term and operator in the expression? Please consider that the expression should have *n* terms and *n-1* operator instances.

I really appreciate your help! Cheers!

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/fMpLgI/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier to use Java's String split method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

For example:

```
String blah = "`now`+`1 day`-`2 days`";
String[] blahArray = blah.split("`");
```

The blahArray will contain: [ "", "now", "+", "1 day", "-", "2 days" ]

Comment: The downside of this approach is you'll have to do data validation as a separate step instead of combining validation with tokenization. But keeping the two separate is sometimes simpler.

Comment: This helped me to realize my question was actually quite silly! As nobody has come up with an answer using only regex, I decided to validate my data in a previous step and then tokenize it, using the approach suggested by @Joe. I'd be really happy, though, if someone could come up with a regex for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can match terms such as the one you are asking about, but they cannot capture groups as you are asking.

When capture groups are included in a repeating pattern they capture group will only contain the last string it matched.

**Example:** `(\d)+` will match `0123` and the first capture group will have `3` in it.

With java you could walk along your string using something such as [`find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) in a loop. [Find example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add operands in both character classes if more than `+` and `-` are supported, then this should do the job:

```
String input = "`now`+`1 day`-`2 days`";
String pattern = "[+-]|[^+-]*";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group().replace('`', ' ').trim());
}
```

This prints

```
now
+
1 day
-
2 days
```

Comment: that will work as long as your operators are not allowed to appear inside the quoted values.

Comment: That is true ;-)