# How to split String without leaving behind empty strings?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to split a string that has two numbers and possibly a letter that will look similar to:

```
(2,3) (2,6) p (8,5) p (5,6)
```

I am trying:

```
String inputTokens = input.split([(),\\s]);
```

but that leaves me with with a bunch of empty strings in the tokens array. How do I stop them from appearing in the first place?

For clarification: By empty string I mean a string containing nothing, not even a space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the "one or more times" greediness quantifier to your character class:

```
String[] inputTokens = input.split("[(),\\s]+");
```

This will result in one leading empty String, which is unavoidable when using the `split()` method and splitting away the immediate start of the String and otherwise no empty Strings.

Comment: This worked really well, thanks! The only empty string left is in the 0th slot, is there an easy way to remove this?

Comment: Instead of splitting away unwanted characters do the opposite: write a regex for what you want to match, create a `java.util.regex.Matcher` and iterate over all the matches. See an example of how that works here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42634031/1749753

Answer (score 1):

```
String inputTokens[] = input.split("[(),\\s]+");
```

This will read the whitespace as part of the regex so there will be no empty entries in your array.

Comment: That hasn't really changed anything, I'm pretty sure it's seeing the ) ( between entries and putting empty strings between them